# Proving that $u_n(t)^2 - u_k(t)^2 = u_{n-k}(t)u_{n+k}(t)$ given a recurrence relation

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

$$u_0(t)=0, \ u_1(t) = 1, \ u_n(t) = tu_{n-1}(t) - u_{n-2}(t)$$
I need to prove that $u_n(t)^2 - u_k(t)^2 = u_{n-k}(t)u_{n+k}(t), \ k =0,1,\dots,n$.

I tried to prove statement by induction:

Let $u_{k'}(t)^2 - u_k(t)^2 = u_{k'-k}(t)u_{k'+k}(t)$.

Then: $$\begin{split}u_{k' + 1}(t)^2 - u_k(t)^2 &= (tu_{k'}(t) - u_{k'-1}(t))^2 - u_k(t)^2\\
&= u_{k'-1-k}(t)u_{k'-1+k}(t) - 2tu_{k'}(t)u_{k'-1}(t) + t^2u_{k'-k}(t)u_{k'+k}(t) + t^2u_k(t)^2\end{split}$$

This result seems useless to me.

I tried to use this formula:
$u_n(t) = t^{n-1} - {n-2 \choose 1}t^{n-3} + {n-3 \choose 2}t^{n-5} + \cdots$ (which is easily proved by induction)

But it's complicated to work with product of two sums.

Comment: You should try to use the `\begin{split} (...) &= (...) \\ &= (...) \\ (...) \end{split}` syntax when formulas get a bit long and unwieldy. I've also made the minor adjustment of adding text to the title: for technical reasons, titles should not be made purely of a math expression. Otherwise, have a nice day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I proved it using [difference equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#difference_equation) (not to be confused with *differential equations*), I will not provide a derivation for the general solution of the difference equation here though since the proof is already too long, but if you like video content, [Michael Penn has an excellent video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HIjFpRxX_Hg) deriving the general solution to such difference equation.

For notation simplicity, I'll let $a_n = u_n(t)$. From the recurrence relation you described we can see that

$$\begin{align}
a_n &= t a_{n-1} - a_{n-2} \\
a_{n+2} &= ta_{n+1} - a_n \\
a_0 &= 0 \\
a_1 &= 1 \\
\end{align}$$

This relation describes a homogeneous linear difference equation with constant coefficients ($t$ is considered constant since it's not a function of $n$), the characteristic equation of which is

$$
r^2 - t r + 1 = 0 \\
r_{1,2} = \frac{t \pm \sqrt{t^2 - 4}}{2}
$$

The roots, $r_1$ and $r_2$, are equal when $\sqrt{t^2 - 4} = 0 \iff t = \pm 2 \iff |t| = 2$, and we have distinct roots otherwise, so we have two cases to consider here:

1. The roots are the same, $|t| = 2$.
2. The roots $r_1$ and $r_2$ are distinct, $|t| \ne 2$.

Let's start with case 1 since it's more straightforward.

In the case of a single root $r$, the solution to our given difference equation is given by

$$a_n = Ar^n + Bnr^n = (A + Bn)r^n$$

Substituting the value for $a_0$ in the function above we get

$$\begin{align}
a_0 = 0 &= (A + B \cdot 0)r^0 \\
A &= 0
\end{align}$$

so our function simplifies to

$$a_n = Bnr^n$$

If $t = 2$, then the characteristic equation will be $r^2 - 2r + 1 = 0$, the left hand side is a perfect square so $(r - 1)^2 = 0$ and we have $r = 1$. Similarly, if $t = -2$, we get $r = -1$. So the only values $r^n$ could take are $1$ (for all $n$ if $r = 1$ and for even $n$ if $r = -1$) and $-1$ (for odd $n$ when $r = -1$).

Now let's prove the statement you gave for case 1.

The left-hand side is
$$\begin{align}
a_n^2 - a_k^2 &= (Bnr^n)^2 - (Bkr^k)^2 \\
&= B^2 n^2 r^{2n} - B^2 k^2 r^{2k} \\
&= B^2 n^2 - B^2 k^2 \\
&= B^2 (n^2 - k^2) \\
&= B^2 (n + k) (n - k)
\end{align}$$
Notice the $r^{2n}$ and $r^{2k}$ are always equal to $1$ regardless of whether $r = 1$ or $r = -1$.

The right-hand side is
$$\begin{align}
a_{n + k} a_{n - k} &= B(n + k)r^{n + k} \cdot B(n - k)r^{n - k} \\
&= B^2 r^{2n + k - k} (n + k) (n - k) \\
&= B^2 r^{2n} (n + k) (n - k) \\
&= B^2 (n + k) (n - k) = \text{L.H.S}
\end{align}$$

Now let's consider case 2 where roots are distinct. In such case, the general solution to $a_n$ is given by

$$a_n = Ar_1^n + Br_2^n$$

Again, substituting in the equation $a_0 = 0$ we get

$$\begin{align}
a_0 = 0 &= Ar_1^0 + B r_2^0 \\
0 &= A + B \\
B &= -A
\end{align}$$

so our function simplifies to

$$a_n = A(r_1^n - r_2^n)$$

From the characteristic equation, it's easy to see that the product of our roots $r_1 r_2$ is always $1$, we'll use this fact throughout the proof for case 2.

Now we prove the statement with case 2.

The left-hand side is
$$\begin{align}
a_n^2 - a_k^2 &= A^2(r_1^n - r_2^n)^2 - A^2(r_1^k - r_2^k)^2 \\
&= A^2 \big( r_1^{2n} - 2 r_1^n r_2^n + r_2^{2n} - r_1^{2k} + 2 r_1^k r_2^k - r_2^{2k} \big) \\
&= A^2 \big( r_1^{2n} + r_2^{2n} - r_1^{2k} - r_2^{2k} - 2 (r_1 r_2)^n + 2 (r_1 
r_2)^k \big) \\
&= A^2 \big( r_1^{2n} + r_2^{2n} - r_1^{2k} - r_2^{2k} - 2 \cdot 1^n + 2 \cdot 1^k \big) \\
&= A^2 \big( r_1^{2n} + r_2^{2n} - r_1^{2k} - r_2^{2k}\big)
\end{align}$$

The right-hand side is
$$\begin{align}
a_{n + k} a_{n - k} &= A(r_1^{n + k} - r_2^{n + k}) \cdot A(r_1^{n - k} - r_2^{n - k}) \\
&= A^2 \big(r_1^{2n} + r_2^{2n} - r_1^{n + k}r_2^{n - k} - r_2^{n + k} r_1^{n - 
k} \big) \\
&= A^2 \big(r_1^{2n} + r_2^{2n} - r_1^{n - k} r_2^{n - k} (r_1^{2k} + r_2^{2k}) \big) \\
&= A^2 \big(r_1^{2n} + r_2^{2n} - (r_1 r_2)^{n - k} (r_1^{2k} + r_2^{2k}) \big) \\
&= A^2 \big(r_1^{2n} + r_2^{2n} - (r_1^{2k} + r_2^{2k}) \big) \\
&= A^2 \big(r_1^{2n} + r_2^{2n} - r_1^{2k} - r_2^{2k} \big) = \text{L.H.S} \quad \blacksquare \\
\end{align}$$

Proving case 2 and thus completing the full proof.

Answer (score 2):

This question is about the sequence of polynomials given by

$$ u_0(t)=0, \quad u_1(t) = 1, \quad u_n(t) = t\,u_{n-1}(t) - u_{n-2}(t). \tag1 $$

There are several methods available. One method is to recognize that

$$ u_n(t) = U_{n-1}(t/2) \tag2 $$

where $\,U_n(x)\,$ is the
[Chebyshev polynomial of the second kind](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheSecondKind.html).
A known property of them is that

$$ U_{n-1}(\cos\theta) = \sin(n\theta)/\sin(\theta). \tag3 $$

Thus, let $\, t = 2\cos(\theta)\,$ to get

$$ u_n(t) = \sin(n\theta)/\sin(\theta). \tag4 $$

The result to prove is

$$ u_n(t)^2 - u_k(t)^2 = u_{n-k}(t)u_{n+k}(t). \tag5 $$

Use equation $(4)$ and elementary algebra to get the equivalent

$$ \sin(n\theta)^2 - \sin(k\theta)^2 = \sin((n-k)\theta)\sin((n+k)\theta). \tag6 $$

This trigonometric identity can be proven in several ways. One of the simplest
is to use the representation of the sine using the exponential function and
elementary algebra to get

$$ \Big(x-\frac1{x}\Big)^2-\Big(y-\frac1{y}\Big)^2 =
\Big(\frac{x}{y}-\frac{y}{x}\Big) \Big(xy-\frac1{xy}\Big). \tag7 $$

---

An alternative method using recursion is as follows. First, since
$\,t\,$ is fixed, drop it from the notation. That is, $u_n := u_n(t).$

Recognize that $\,u_n\,$ is the
[Lucas sequence of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_sequence). That is, $\, u_n = U_n(t,1).\,$

The next step is to prove for a fixed $\,k\,$ the addition theorem

$$ u_{n+k} = u_n u_{k+1} - u_{n-1} u_k. \tag8 $$

A standard technique is to verify that both sides of the equality have
the same two initial values and the same recursion as $\,u_n.\,$ Then
the equality is true for all $\,n\,$ by induction. Same thing for

$$ u_{n-k} =  u_{n-1} u_k - u_n u_{k-1}. \tag9 $$

Combine equations $(8)$ and $(9)$ to get

$$ u_{n-k}u_{n+k} = (u_{n-1} u_k - u_n u_{k-1})(u_n u_{k+1} - u_{n-1} u_k)
=: T_{n,k}. \tag{10} $$

Next, prove that the sum and product of $\,u_{n-1}\,$ and $\,u_{n+1}\,$ is

$$ u_{n-1}+u_{n+1} = t\,u_n, \quad u_{n-1}u_{n+1} = u_n^2 - 1 \tag{11} $$

by induction using the recursion equation $(1)$ and elementary algebra.

Expand $\,T_{n,k},\,$ the right side of equation $(10)$ to get

$$ T_{n,k} = u_n u_{n-1}u_k( u_{k+1}+u_{k-1}) - u_n^2u_{k-1}u_{k+1}
- u_k^2u_{n-1}u_{n+1}. \tag{12} $$

Finally, use the results in equation $(11)$ to get

$$ T_{n,k}=(u_n^2-1)u_k^2-u_n^2(u_k^2-1) = u_n^2-u_k^2.\tag{13}$$